# ng-bootstrap accordion is not working in for loop in Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

It does not work in for loop.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let p of [0,1,2]">
    <ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true">
        <ngb-panel  id={{p}}>
            <ng-template ngbPanelTitle>
                title 
            </ng-template>
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
                content 
            </ng-template>
        </ngb-panel>
    </ngb-accordion>
</ng-container>
```

The id should be unique. Other panels should close when a new panel is opened.
Example: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples
(One open panel at a time)

Comment: Pay attention to you ```ngFor``` position : instead of generating 1 accordion with 3 panels, you generate 3 accordions with 1 panel in each of them.

Comment: Thank you. Added <div *ngFor="let p of [0,1,2]"> above 'ngb-panel'. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the working code snippet

```
<ngb-accordion [closeOthers]="true">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let result of results; let i= index">
    <ngb-panel id="ngb-panel-{{i}}" title="{{result}}">
      <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
        <div>
          hello content{{i}}
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-panel>
  </ng-container>
</ngb-accordion>
```